# Categorical Data with multiple categories (variable selection)

Tags: computational-statistics

I have a model with multiple categories for several categorical variables. I'm interested in prediction. So far I've been using step(). The issue with it is that it doesn't treat variables with multiple categories as 1 block, so to speak. So in the output, I might get 2 of the levels of x1 and say 1 of the levels of x2. My question is, is there a way to do this using step() s.t., an entire variable (as in all the categories) are selected/rejected? And if not, is there some other way of doing this in R, using some other command?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to not use `step()` at all. It has many problems and this is only one.

Instead of `step()` you can create several reasonable models (using your own powers of reason) and compare them using AIC or BIC.

Using any automated variable selection scheme is going to cause problems.

Comment: I would add that manual variable selection presents almost the same problems.

Comment: I can add that if you, against the advice here, still want to do variable selection, there is in R stepAIC in package MASS, which behaves as you want.